# checkBox onClick

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Нужна помощь с чекбокс. На главной активности я чекбоксом включаю или отключаю музыку. Но так как у чекбокса метод onClick, следовательно при открытии приложения чекбокс не работает, до нажатия на него, а мне нужно выставить значение и чтобы при перезапуске приложения не нужно было снова тыкать на чекбокс.

```
public class Stage extends Activity {
    CheckBox musicOff;
    public SharedPreferences mSet;
    public static final String NAME_PREFERENCES = "mysetting";
    public static final String BOOL_CHECKBOX = "checkboxset";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stage);
        musicOff = findViewById(R.id.musicCb);
        mSet = getSharedPreferences(NAME_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (mSet.contains(BOOL_CHECKBOX)) {
            musicOff.setChecked(mSet.getBoolean(BOOL_CHECKBOX, true));
        }
    }
    public void checkBoxClicked(View view) {
        if (musicOff.isChecked()) {
            startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        } else {
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mSet = getSharedPreferences(NAME_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSet.edit();
        // Чекбокс сохранение значения при выходе из приложения-/-активности
        editor.putBoolean(BOOL_CHECKBOX, musicOff.isChecked());
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: а что не получается у вас, не то значение чекбокса сохраняется?

Comment: т.е. при запуске еcли чекбокс отключен, то музыка не должна играть, а она играет, только после того как я пальцем переткну чекбокс музыка останавливается. При запуске чекбокс получается не участвует

Comment: так добавьте этот кусок туда же где вы данные с настроек:
`if (mSet.getBoolean(BOOL_CHECKBOX, true)) {
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
} else {
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}` и оно будет выключать тоже и музыку

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы не плодить кучу одинаковых кусков кода, и чтобы все выглядело красиво предлагаю сделать отдельную функцию:

```
public void workingWithService(boolean enableService){
      if(enableService){
         startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      }
      else{
         stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      }
}
```

тогда функция `checkBoxClicked` будет такой:

```
public void checkBoxClicked (View view) {
     workingWithService(musicOff.isChecked())           
}
```

а в `onCreate()` будет так:

```
if(mSet.contains(BOOL_CHECKBOX)){
   Boolean enabled = mSet.getBoolean(BOOL_CHECKBOX, true);
   musicOff.setChecked(enabled );
   workingWithService(enabled);
}
```

И я бы советовал поставить в `getBoolean(BOOL_CHECKBOX, true)` по-умолчанию  `false` чтобы музыка по-умолчанию была выключенной, но это уже на ваше усмотрение :)

Comment: и вправду красиво, спасибо